# Is there a way to strip true/false values from a lua table

Tags: lua

I need to create a new table without the = true or false values
Currently the table looks like the following

```
local t = { foo = "true", bar = "false" }
```

to

```
local t = { foo, bar }
```

I tried searching, but couldn't find a example

Comment: I'm not sure if you are doing this on purpose, but there are real boolean value `true` and `false`. You are using strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` and `bar` are table keys. So you actually want to create a list of table keys.

```
local result = {}
for k in pairs(t) do table.insert(result, k) end
```

You do this by iterating over the table and storing every key in a new table. Please note that `t` has no order so the order of `result` is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

```
local t = (function(...)local ret={} 
  for key,val in pairs(...) do --print(k,v)
    ret[#ret+1]=k
  end
  return ret
end){ foo = "true", bar = "false" }
```

Comment: You should add some text to explain your answer, and maybe think about naming your function to help convey what it does. try and make your answer more approachable for someone less experienced with lua.